# cannot update record from date to character string

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I cannot update the record of date to character. in my problem i want to update the date to "NULL" value. Please help.

**here is the screenshot**

[image]

[image]

Comment: type cast error. you can get rid off this error by removing single quotes for  "NULL"  to null

Comment: Thank you! It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null is a special value and it does not take quotes around it:

```
UPDATE a_wty_prep_header SET process_date = NULL WHERE ro_no = 'RO004446'
```

Single quotes are how you indicate string literals in SQL Server.